# Need help with Wordpress menu and redirecting pages

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a template with 2 menus, a top primary menu and a secondary menu.

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'container_class' => 'menu-header', 'theme_location' => 'primary' ) ); ?>
```

and these menu options :

- Home
- Projects
- Contact

Now I have a secondary menu that is visible when someone accesses "Projects". and the follwing menu options :

- Overview
- Project A
- Project B

Now in this scenario I have 6 pages, one for every menu option. But I do not want to use the "Project" page. If someone clicks "Porjects" on the primary menu, I want that the "Overview" page is actually loaded.

The second problem is with the style. When I have "Overview" activated I also want to have the secondary menu option "Overview" highlighted, which works, but also the menu option on the primary menu "Projects".

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

At least for your first question, using the custom menu, you should be able to add the Overview page in place of Projects, and rename it Projects. That also may fix your second question as well.